# Display sub-property in table tag (Spring Roo supplied tag library)

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp-tags, spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo. There is `table:table` and `table:column` tags.

**How to display sub-property of colections elements in table?**

In straightforward way it doesnt work:

```
<table:table data="${knowledgebase.concepts}" id="l_domain_Concept" path="/concepts" z="user-managed">
  <table:column id="c_domain_Concept_translations" property="defaultTranslation.name"  z="user-managed" />
</table:table>
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'defaultTranslation.name' not found on type domain.data.Concept
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified table.tagx so it could be used with sub-properties and Spring converting capabilities.

```
<c:forTokens items="${columnProperties}" delims="," var="column" varStatus="num">
<c:set var="prop" value="${ item }" />
    <c:forTokens items="${column}" delims="." var="subprop">
        <c:set var="prop" value="${ prop[subprop]}" />
    </c:forTokens>
<c:set var="columnMaxLength" value="${lengths[num.count - 1]}" scope="request"/>
 <td>
     <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${not convert}">
             <c:out value="${columnMaxLength lt 0 ? prop : fn:substring(prop, 0, columnMaxLength)}" />
         </c:when>
         <c:otherwise>
             <spring:eval expression="prop" />
     </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>
 </td>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same issue. But I used this logic and its working. what does this c:when test="${not convert}" conditions check??

Comment: It's flag to use Spring converting capabilities. It is one of jsp directive attribute.

Comment: @abele, Will this only work a single level of sub-properties, or will it be able to go down multiple sub-property levels, eg: employee.supervisor.name

Comment: @ThatGuyGrant sorry, can't help you. I have moved on form Java and Spring Roo to Python camp.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `PROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields/table.tagx`. At line 78, you should see `<c:set var="columnDatePattern" value="${patterns[num.count-1]}" />`. Put under that line, the following piece of code:

```
<!-- Get the last descendant property -->
<c:set var="prop" value="${item}" />
<c:forTokens items="${column}" delims="." var="subprop">
    <c:if test="${not empty prop}">
        <c:set var="prop" value="${prop[subprop]}" />
    </c:if>
</c:forTokens>
<!-- Now under tag c:choose below, please change from "item[column]" into "prop" -->
<!-- // End of Get the last descendant property. -->
```

Don't forget to change from `"item[column]"` into `"prop"`. For example, the changed lines should be:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${columnType eq 'date'}">
        <spring:escapeBody>
            <fmt:formatDate value="${prop}" pattern="${fn:escapeXml(columnDatePattern)}" var="colTxt" />
        </spring:escapeBody>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${columnType eq 'calendar'}">
        <spring:escapeBody>
            <fmt:formatDate value="${prop.time}" pattern="${fn:escapeXml(columnDatePattern)}" var="colTxt"/>
        </spring:escapeBody>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="colTxt">
            <spring:eval expression="prop" htmlEscape="false" />
        </c:set>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit entity file Concepts.java :

```
@Transient
public String getDefaultTranslationName(){
         return defaultTranslation.getName();
}
```

After , you edit  to:

```
<table:column id="c_domain_Concept_translations" property="DefaultTranslationName"  z="user-managed" />
```

Hope can help you !